# Xpath: find an element value from a match of id attribute to id anchor

Tags: xpath

I would like to find the value of an element matched on id attribute for which I only have the ref - the bit with #, the anchor.

I am looking for the value of partyId:

```
 < party id="partyA" >
   < partyId >THEID< /partyId >
```

but to get there I only have the href from the following

```
  < MyData >
    < MyReference href="#partyA" />
```

Strip the # sign does not look good to me.

Any hints?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two possible solutions :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't provided complete XML documents, I have to use `//` -- a practice I strongly recommend to avoid.

**Suppose that**

`$vDataRef`

**is defined as**

`//MyData/MyReference/@href`

and its string value is `"#partyA"`, **then one possible XPath expression that selects the wanted node is**:

```
//party[@id=substring($vDataRef,2)]
```

In case the XML document has a DTD in which the `id` attribute of `party` is defined to be of type `ID`, then it is more convenient and efficient to use the standard XPath function **[`id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id)**:

```
id(substring($vDataRef,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your ID as a variable already (lets say `$myId`), then try using:

```
//party[contains($myId, @id)]
```

The [contains() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) will look to see on each matching node whether or not the `partyId` attibute is in the value that you pass in.

Alternatively (as that could be considered 'ropey'), you can try:

```
//party[@id=substring($myId, 2, 1 div 0)]
```

the [substring() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) should be a little more precise.

Comment: It's OK to use p/2 `fn:substring()`, you don't need that `INF` expression.